# What is the point of an input resistance on a tee to the ground in a buffer op-amp?

Tags: operational-amplifier, buffer

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fIej0a.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Does it factor in to closed loop gain/bandwidth calculations?

Comment: needs more background: Where's that circuit from?

Comment: It depends on what freq you are talking about, but below ~10MHz the resistor does nothing. You can think of the inputs to the op amp as GOhm resistors. Putting a 10k in parallel even with the series source resistance of Vi will not drop the voltage enough for you to care about. The inputs to the op amp will also have pF's of capacitance that you will need to worry about at high speed.

Comment: What's your source impedance? And, as Marcus asked, where's that from i.e. what's the context?

Comment: Add detail asap as others have requested or the kneecappers will put the question on hold. | Context needed. R1 (10K) adds a sensibly finite load to V1. Without it V1 "sees" an exceedingly high resistance. Offset and bias currents will flow in R1. As these are small wrt typical V1 values , Vbias = Ivarious x R1 will be small. Without R1 these currents must flow in C1. Usually taht will not matter. In some cases it may.

Answer (score 5):

As shown, it does nothing but waste power, because V1 is an ideal voltage source.

However, there are at least two reasons why you might see a resistor in a similar configuration.

#### DC path to ground

If the input is capacitively coupled, no DC current will pass, and the DC voltage will "float", possibly causing saturation. A pull-down resistor on the input will create a path for DC currents down to ground, so that the input is 0 volts at DC.

The value will typically be relatively high, in the order of 10 kΩ or higher.

#### Impedance matching

Certain signals are meant to be *matched*. This is not the right place to explain when, but typically you see this when higher frequencies are involved, and/or with longer cables. The resistor is chosen to match the characteristic impedance of the cable, and will typically be relatively low. Common values are 50 Ω, 75 Ω etc.

Comment: Forgive me, the resistor is actually a 10kΩ one - I was unfamiliar with how to alter the values (first-timer), and considered it an unimportant detail until your comment. Thank you for your feedback, it has been edited to reflect this.

Comment: @ReacherT The problem isn't the value of the resistor - any value will just "waste power", because the voltage source is an _ideal_ voltage source. That means it will "override" anything else that can affect a voltage, for example a resistor.

Answer (score 1):

That resistor changes input impedance. So one reason to put 100ohm resistor there is case when you need change input impedance to 100ohm.